# actionButton is not working in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I set up 2 actionButton in my shiny app to insert user input into database and delete one record from DB.

```
mainPanel(
                            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                                    tabPanel("Phase1",
                                            column(4,uiOutput("Phase1", inline = FALSE),
                                                    wellPanel(
                                                            actionButton("P1_Add", "Add",icon=icon("plus-circle")),
                                                            actionButton("P1_Del", "Del",icon=icon("minus-circle"))
                                                                )),
                                            column(6,h1("Phase1 Input data is put here"),dataTableOutput("Phase1_Data"))

                                            ), 
                                    tabPanel("Phase2",uiOutput("Phase2",inline=FALSE)), 
                                    tabPanel("Phase3")
                            )
                    )
```

and i also defined a observe in server.R to response my click. but seems not working

```
            obs_p1_add<-observe({

                    if(input$P1_Add)
                    {
                        cat("just click add button")
                        cat("test")
                        print (input$P1_Add)
                        output$Phase2<-  renderUI({ 
                                list(h4("ha! change"))
                                })

                    }

                })
```

any one can teach me where went wrong?  thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me!

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Phase1",
                           column(4,uiOutput("Phase1", inline = FALSE),
                                  wellPanel(
                                    actionButton("P1_Add", "Add",icon=icon("plus-circle")),
                                    actionButton("P1_Del", "Del",icon=icon("minus-circle"))
                                  )),
                           column(6,h1("Phase1 Input data is put here"),dataTableOutput("Phase1_Data"))

                  ), 
                  tabPanel("Phase2",uiOutput("Phase2",inline=FALSE)), 
                  tabPanel("Phase3")
      )
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  obs_p1_add<-observe({

    if(input$P1_Add)
    {
      cat("just click add button")
      cat("test")
      print (input$P1_Add)
      output$Phase2<-  renderUI({ 
        list(h4("ha! change"))
      })

    }

  })

})
```

Text renders in second tab after click:

[image]

Comment: hi Johannes, what is your R and shiny version?  thanks!

Comment: R version 3.1.1, shiny 0.10.2.1, firefox 36.0.1

Comment: thanks!  the code works after i re-install R and Shiny it works.  i will accept the answer. have a nice day.

Comment: Fine! Could you click the check mark next to my answer? This signals that your problem has been solved. Thanks!